# In Android phone, after move .apk from /data/app to /system/app, can I use "adb shell pm list package -f" get .apk's true path?

Tags: android, package, adb

In Android phone, after move .apk from /data/app to /system/app, can I use "adb shell pm list package -f" get .apk's true path? I have not android phone with root, so I can't test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `adb shell pm list package -f`, `-f` filter is to see their associated file.

If the /data/app .apk is moved to system/app the above command still show the .apk true path i.e., it will show it is in data/app. But, the app will crash if it is started.